# Pagination URL order

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I'm trying to create a filter by taxonomy for a custom post type.

When I use the filter option it creates this URL which doesn't work: `/projecten-test/?branche=industrie/page/2/.`

But when I enter this url manually, it DOES work: `/projecten-test/page/2/?branche=industrie`

How can I accomplish this automaticly, should I change the method in which I add the php GET to the URL, of should I change the wp_rewrite on the bottom of this function:

// Use pagination on custom post type
function paginate() {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

```
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
$pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => true,
    'type' => 'plain',
    'prev_text'    => __('« Vorige'),
    'next_text'    => __('Volgende »')
);
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
echo paginate_links( $pagination );
```

}

Comment: when you click on a link to another page, how does WordPress know what term was chosen on the previous page? also- note that [taxonomy names should not contain capital letters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), and use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to modify main query, never use `query_posts`.

Comment: I could store it in the URL using the php $_GET method, guess I should edit the wp_rewrite rule or something?

Comment: I can see that it is in this part: `$pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),` The page/2/ of the link is in this part, but the taxonomy seems to be added before the '[here]/page/2/' part...

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to fix it. Not sure if this is the best way to do it so please enlighten me if I'm wrong:

By changing:

```
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
```

to:

```
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
```

It's working. Now all I have to do is to create a fall back if you enter a taxonomy from page 4 to the new taxonomy on page 1.